# It is known that the line doesn’t pass through the origin, what is projection of vector $\vec{a}$ onto line L

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Question :

Let $L$ have a vector from $\vec{x}$ = t $\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ + $\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$, and let $\vec{a}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
    2 \\ 6\end{bmatrix}$. Then find projection of $\vec{a}$ onto L.

My attempt so far :

I am aware that line doesn’t pass through the origin, so it is not a subspace so direct formula won’t be used here. So, I turned vector form of line to Cartesian form :

$$ y = 1-x$$

[image]

What would be my next step, what is the geometric intuition behind such projection?

Any help is highly appreciated